# Android APK expansion STATUS_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: apk-expansion-files

Android APK Expansion not downloading, status always
**STATUS_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**.

Note : PUBLIC_KEY replaced with playstore key.
       Version of APK and expansion file is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are testing too much.

Did you check on other devices ??